# Unable to place a bounty (unknown bug)

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounty

There is some kind of bug that is not letting me put a bounty on a particular question. I have enough rep, the essential waiting period has passed and I have no other bounty currently running.

I have not encountered such a problem before, so I have no idea what caused it. I had tried in the morning also, but it didn't work. I have put bounties before under same conditions (Windows 7, Google Chrome latest version) on Puzzling and on Math. (And I don't think I have a bad connection.)

I've uploaded screenshots [here](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B_tKaDhguEEzfkg1XzlVSmRqdlpzc0VwSTRucTk2eUFOamliZ09lUkZOR2Z6ZERYZlZESjg&usp=sharing).

Comment: Cross-site dup: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/252002/180276

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug has been fixed (see [the Mother Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/252022/180276)).

You should now be able to set bounties again.